# Using Gparted to increase partition (No extended partitions)

Tags: xubuntu, gparted

I've been trying to increase the size of my /home partition. In most tutorials there is an extended partition already available but I can't find one in my system. I have configured my Ubuntu System to have very little storage and i would like to make it bigger so that it can actually be usable.

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYvjm.png)

Comment: You have to remove some of the disk space off of your Windows partition and then allocate that space to /home. Be very careful when doing this. I highly recommend backing up all of your Windows data.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This is why I don't recommend multi-partitioning Ubuntu, especially on a smallish disk.

Your `/dev/sdb3` NTFS (C:) partition needs to be reduced by using Windows `Disk Management` application.

Your `/dev/sdb5` (/) and `/dev/sdb6` (/home) both need to be expanded using `gparted`.

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Windows and Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot into Windows
- start the `Disk Management` application
- reduce `/dev/sdb3` (C:) partition by the amount that you wish to add to `/dev/sdb5` and `/dev/sdb6`. Probably around 50G.

  - **Note**: You may have to temporarily disable hibernation and page file to do this.
- reboot Windows and confirm proper operation

---

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in "Try Ubuntu" mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** `/dev/sdb5` partition all the way left
- **resize** the right size of `/dev/sdb5` and increase it by approximately 10G
- **move** `/dev/sdb6` partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of `/dev/sdb6` all the way right, increasing it by approximately 40G
- click the Apply icon

Comment: I'll try this thank you. If this doesn't work I'll try reinstalling ubuntu and allocate more space.

Comment: @IesaMuhammed  If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @IesaMuhammed Status please...

Comment: @IesaMuhammed Status please...

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not have an Extended Partition because your system was formatted with a [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). When there are six non-extended partitions, it's [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), not the old [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Partition_table_entries) which was first defined back in DOS days. https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/explains the difference.

Since changing the partition table is the easiest way to completely lose all your data, please make a backup first, and verify the destination of the backup (be it external drive or cloud) matches the source data. Then, repeat the backup to a different external drive or cloud and verify that.